# UnsupportedClassVersionError: JWMCFRE003 bad major version ; class=io/swagger/v3jaxrs2/integration/OpenApiServlet, offcet=6

Tags: java, swagger, websphere, websphere-8, javacompiler

Swagger version in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer-v2</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

properties in pom.xml

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

In Idea, Settings - Java compiler - Target bytecode version - 1.6

I'm using WebSphere 8.5.5.9 on Windows server.
On local WebSphere I don't have this problem, only on the server.

Comment: Maven properties only set byte code version for you code not for the dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I`m understand this. But how I can set the same byte code version for both?

Comment: Rather, which version of Swagger should I use to have bytecode version 1.6?

Comment: You should find a compatible version of the dependency